# How do i make groups of shapes or likes of triangle, anchor about its center or corner in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to make this collectables anchor about its center and the canyon anchor about its right corner.

```
 collectable = {
    x_pos: 100,
    y_pos: 310,
    size: 40,
    isFound: false,
  };


fill(255, 215, 0);
    ellipse(collectable.x_pos, collectable.y_pos + 100, collectable.size);
    fill(218, 165, 32);
    ellipse(collectable.x_pos, collectable.y_pos + 100, collectable.size - 10);
    fill(255, 215, 0);
    text("£", collectable.x_pos - 5, collectable.y_pos + 107);
    textSize(collectable.size - 20);
```

```
canyon = {
    x_pos: 200,
    width: 100,
  };


rect(canyon.x_pos + 20, 432, canyon.width, 300);
  fill(100, 155, 255);
  rect(canyon.x_pos + 20, 432, canyon.width, 100);
  fill(210, 105, 30);
  rect(canyon.x_pos + 20, 432, canyon.width - 90, 300);
  fill(240, 128, 128);
  rect(canyon.x_pos + 110, 432, canyon.width - 90, 300);
```

Trying to make this collectables anchor about its center and the canyon anchor about its right corner.